# How can open whatsapp api link in the same new tab every time

Tags: html

I have a whatsapp contact link on my page. I want to open it in a new tab. But if it is already opened, i want to go to this tab (the already opened) instead of open a new tab.

I tried:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=">Whatsapp</a>
```

But every time it opens in a new tab, any ideas?

Comment: doesn't whatsapp close the tab on redirect?

Comment: Impossible you can't see or have informations about other tabs on the client side. For privacy and security

Answer (score 0):

For a better solution, try opening the whatsapp tab in a new popup instead of the browser tab.

As a page can not keep track of other pages/tabs open on the client side.

You can use a popup to open up the whatsapp page, and can control it through javascript/jQuery

The latter page can also control the main page through javascript commands like `parent.`

Answer (score -2):

Try rewriting the link as ,

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=">Whatsapp</a>
```